# Google/Analytics.h file not found when Testing

Tags: swift, unit-testing, google-analytics, xcode7

I am including the BridgingHeader.h however on importing Google/Analytics.h it can't find the file.

This works fine in the application, it only throws the error under testing.

Not sure what the issue is so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by adding the Google Analytics pod to both the tests and uitests targets by opening up your podfile and modifying it as shown:

```
target 'MyApp' do
pod 'Google/Analytics'
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
pod 'Google/Analytics'
end

target 'MyAppUITests' do
pod 'Google/Analytics'
end
```

Once that was complete I had to run `pod install` twice and then it worked.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try.

Answer (score 5):

Spent near 2 hours on searching and finally found correct solution to all that madness! Accepted solution above is working, but gives a lot of `Class GAIUtil is implemented in both...` warnings which is not quite right that means.

### Solution

You need to use cocoapods 1.0.0.beta6+

Your test target should be defined in your Podfile as next:

```
target 'App' do
    pod 'GoogleAnalytics' , '~> 3.0'
    # your other pods

    target 'AppTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # your other testing pods/frameworks
    end
end
```

Do `pod update`.

All that found there https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4626#issuecomment-210402349